# git-cmd vs cmder -> 2x version

Tags: git, cmd, path, version, cmder

Hello I have a little problem. I am trying to run `unGit`, but it keeps showing errors.

I've figured out that I have different version on my cmder than git-cmd:

[image: screenshot]

Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your `PATH` environment variable does include `C:\1_Programmy\Git` first (where I suppose you have installed git 2.7, or maybe it is in `C:\Program Files\Git`)

If your `PATH` does include that folder *first*, then [`unGit`](https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit) should pick it up.

The [OP Kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5776437/kyle) confirms that `cmder` (in which ungit does run) has a git of its own.

> cmder have portable `git` inside `D:\99 Portable\9_Programing\cmder\vendor\msysgit`.
>   so you need to change `.bat` or add new git in msygit

If the PATH of cmder also includes `C:\1_Programmy\Git`, that will be enough for the new git to be taken into account.

Comment: @Kyle Make sure to launch ungit from a CMD session where your PATH is indeed that. Check if ungit starting script does not define its own path.

Comment: Problem is in the cmder console because ungit runing inside that console.

Comment: @Kyle What is the PATH in that cmder console?

Comment: `D:\99 Portable\9_Programing\cmder\bin`

Comment: @Kyle Is there a git.exe in that folder?

Comment: Yes it is but I found solution. I did not know, that cmder have portable git inside `D:\99 Portable\9_Programing\cmder\vendor\msysgit` ... so you need to change .bat or add new git in msygit. Thank you @VonC

Comment: @Kyle Great. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.